# generation of random number in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random

I would like to generate three sets of random variables and I dont want them to be the same

for example if I want to generate the following sets ranged from 1 to 10

```
Set1= [ 1 4 ] 
set2= [ 3 5 ]
Set3= [ 7 9]
```

Comment: Could they have common elements?

Comment: No they have not common elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of unique random numbers using the function "randperm" and then divide the array into sets.

```
x = randperm(10,6);
Set1 = x(1:2);
Set2 = x(3:4);
Set3 = x(5:6);
```

Answer (score 0):

After choosing two elements for each set, it's essential to randomize the remaining elements to choose from for the next iteration . The code below is trying to achieve it -

```
set123 = zeros(3,2); %// Pre-allocate for the output
array1 = 1:10; %// Array of numbers to choose from for the first iteration
for k = 1:3
    %// Create many possible combinations of such two numbers from the sets.
    %// The sets would have 10 elements to choose from at the start and
    %// then 8 and then 6.
    combs = nchoosek(array1,2);

    %// At each stage all the possible combinations of the pairs must be
    %// juggled and one of them must be selected randomly and then indexed
    %// to get the set for this iteration
    choosen_rowind = randperm(size(combs,1),1);
    set123(k,:) = combs(choosen_rowind,:);

    %// Setup the array of numbers left to choose from the next iteration
    array1 = setdiff(array1,set123);    
end
%// set123 is the desired output in a single array
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to take `r`-times-`c` random variables (in your case `r=3`, `c=2`) from the set {`m`,`m+1`,...,`n`} (in your case `n=1` and `m=10`), without repetition. I assume you want a (jointly) uniform distribution.

For that you use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
result = reshape(randsample(m:n, r*c), r, c);
```